# Websocket communicate after the network goes down

Tags: websocket

Case:

A WebSocket connection have been established between the client and server endpoint.
Now I have the network connection go down (for example the ADSL dies), after 10 min I recover the network, I find that the client and server are still able to communicate with each
other. Why?

Note:

The client was developed with Java-WebSocket framework, and the client did with ws4py.

Comment: I believe they are [detecting offline/online status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events) and queue messages or something.

Comment: apparently the timeout value was large enough that no side detected that the other wasn't responding anymore and continued as usual.

Answer (score 1):

1 - If they did not try to exchange any data and only the connection (not the endpoints) between them is down, this is normal behaviour.

2 - If the websocket connection ended, Browser may have re-established it without you knowing about it. I just checked that this is not normal behaviour. But maybe there is some parameter somewhere :-)